# LiveServerTestCase - Internal server error contact administrator

Tags: django, selenium, django-testing

I have spent all day, trying to figure out why `LiveServerTestCase` keeps failing to run to no avail.... google searched, dived intro django docs yet found nothing... Looking at this stack trace what can one make from it and how to fix it.

It throws and ImportError at the end with no information whatsoever where the error occured. Am I missing something? With a whole chunk of importlib bootstrap confusions.... These are my first suites with LiveServerTestCase, for the record I am trying to configure LiveServerTestCase with selenium and I have managed to get selenium to work with remote urs this far.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 244, in _legacy_get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 24, in process_request
    i18n_patterns_used, prefixed_default_language = is_language_prefix_patterns_used(urlconf)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/i18n.py", line 29, in is_language_prefix_patterns_used
    for url_pattern in get_resolver(urlconf).url_patterns:
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'my_portal.my_portal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1225, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1225, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 157, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 142, in handle_uncaught_exception
    callback, param_dict = resolver.resolve_error_handler(500)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 418, in resolve_error_handler
    callback = getattr(self.urlconf_module, 'handler%s' % view_type, None)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'my_portal.my_portal'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 244, in _legacy_get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 62, in process_request
    if self.should_redirect_with_slash(request):
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 80, in should_redirect_with_slash
    not is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 158, in is_valid_path
    resolve(path, urlconf)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 27, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 362, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'my_portal.my_portal'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/wsgiref/handlers.py", line 137, in run
    self.result = application(self.environ, self.start_response)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1225, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/test/testcases.py", line 1225, in __call__
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/wsgi.py", line 157, in __call__
    response = self.get_response(request)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 124, in get_response
    response = self._middleware_chain(request)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 43, in inner
    response = response_for_exception(request, exc)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 93, in response_for_exception
    response = handle_uncaught_exception(request, get_resolver(get_urlconf()), sys.exc_info())
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 142, in handle_uncaught_exception
    callback, param_dict = resolver.resolve_error_handler(500)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 418, in resolve_error_handler
    callback = getattr(self.urlconf_module, 'handler%s' % view_type, None)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'my_portal.my_portal'
------------------------------ Captured log call -------------------------------
exception.py               135 ERROR    Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 244, in _legacy_get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/locale.py", line 24, in process_request
    i18n_patterns_used, prefixed_default_language = is_language_prefix_patterns_used(urlconf)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/urls/i18n.py", line 29, in is_language_prefix_patterns_used
    for url_pattern in get_resolver(urlconf).url_patterns:
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'my_portal.my_portal'
exception.py               135 ERROR    Internal Server Error: /favicon.ico
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 41, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 244, in _legacy_get_response
    response = middleware_method(request)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 62, in process_request
    if self.should_redirect_with_slash(request):
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py", line 80, in should_redirect_with_slash
    not is_valid_path(request.path_info, urlconf) and
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 158, in is_valid_path
    resolve(path, urlconf)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 27, in resolve
    return get_resolver(urlconf).resolve(path)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 362, in resolve
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 405, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 398, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/fenn/projects/portal/venv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 944, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 956, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ImportError: No module named 'my_portal.my_portal'
```

Comment: Django isn't able to import the following modules: systers_portal.systers_portal and my_portal.my_portal. Check that you have them installed and your import statements using them are right.

Comment: That's exactly what the question is saying! Where do I check? Where did it try the imports?

Comment: update it with your test code